# Asp.NET MVC Model Binding Not Picking Up A Value for List Item

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I've got an object with a list defined inside it which points to a type that can be inherited. From what I understand MVC's default model binder will always instance the base type when reading data back in to this array from a form so by default I will have a list of base types.

So I need to use my own model binder and override `CreateModel` to instance a specific type (say from a hidden field). However when I do this and use

```
bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ModelType")
```

it always returns `null` even though through using fiddler I can see that form value `Settings[0].ModelType` contains my objects type and I need this value in `CreateModel` to instance the correct type.

Comment: Just a bit more info I think the "scope" of the model binder (sorry can't think of what to call it) is messing it up. I figure that if the object is in its instancing stage it should be in the Settings[0] part of the form but it seems to be just pulling back all of the parent objects form data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. If your array objects need to be typed based on each item you need to use the following call to get "into" the array item

```
bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".ModelType")
```

I'm not sure if this is the standard way to do it. If anyone has any better suggestions feel free to add them